# "Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object" when using PDO

Tags: php, pdo

How do I resolve the following error?

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object
>   in index.php on line 27 Call Stack: 0.0000 644064 1. {main}()
>   index.php:0

This is the code I'm running so far:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM pm_user WHERE name='.$_SESSION['pmname'].'';
$result = $pdo->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc(); // line 27
echo $row['img'];
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hmm. I can't mark this as a duplicate like we have been correctly doing for the past two years, because the "mark as duplicate" system has been broken. Regardless, please do a _search_ before posting questions. This one has been answered _hundreds of thousands of times_. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14656942/fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-fetch-assoc-on-a-non-object-when-usin

Comment: Also, why on earth are you using PDO but not _prepared statements_?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problems are:

- You are interpolating a value inside of your query.
  This is **bad and wrong**. You should use PDO's *prepared statements* feature instead.
- In the process of doing this **bad and wrong** interpolation, you forgot to add *string quotations*, making your SQL query invalid.
- You failed to do *any error checking whatsoever* on `->query()`; when `query()` fails, it returns `FALSE` and thus you tried to perform `->fetch()` on `FALSE`.

Fix all these things.

Comment: I really don't like answer that first tell 'Use prepared statements, don't use the mysql extenstion, the answer to your problem... ähmmmm. less important'

Comment: @hek2mgl: I'm sorry that you "don't like" it but, regardless, by far the most important thing is that we continue to try to stem the tide of _reams and reams of dangerously buggy code_ from streaming on to the internet. The needs of the many over a period of potentially decades, outweigh the needs of \@methusalah over the next ten minutes. Vastly so.

Answer (score 1):

When you have an error in a program, **please check return values of all functions that you call**

```
// use quote or prepared statements to prevent from 
// SQL injection attacks!
$pmname = $pdo->quote($_SESSION['pmname']);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM pm_user WHERE name=$pmname";

$result = $pdo->query($sql);
if($result === FALSE) {
    echo 'oops! the query failed! ';
    print_r($pdo->errorInfo());
}

$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

if($row) {
    echo $row['img'];
} else {
    echo 'the query return no records :(';
}
```

Additionally you should consider to set the php.ini directive `display_errors=1` *during development* to see php error messages instead of a 'white screen'. You can also enable it per script with the following line of code:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Comment: Why use PDO but then interpolate a variable? That's really silly.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I used qoute() (in this example) to keep things simple, but at least mentioning the risk of a SQL injection. Can you tell me in which case the quote() is less secure than a prepared statement?

Comment: `->quote()` is sufficient, if the connection charset is correct. However, quote -as it says- also adds the SQL strings' single quotes itself, so the manual quotes around the interpolated variables are redundant / will lead to an error.

Comment: @mario yepp, you are right. I just don't like this stupid 10000ths answer: 'use prepared statements' on all mysql related questions

Comment: @hek2mgl: Believe me, I don't like the fact that this is the 10,000th question on which it has to be written. Why won't people _read_ and _learn_ already? Then we can stop.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm with you of course. But there are soooo many problems in the code of a beginner... As I where a beginner, I fear I would just not understand what the prepared statement has to do with the question.

Comment: @hek2mgl: Let's tackle them together, head-on.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit One more thing to mention. (just for completeness, I'm with you as I said').. When talking about prepared statments, you'll have to make sure you're talking about **server side** prepared statements. This means there are libraries that just 'simulate' prepared statements in the client libraries. as syntactic sugar. When using such a lib and there's a bug in that code than prepared statements are vulnerable again. When the same code runs on systems with different libraries but the programmer don't cares because of feeling safe ... voila... (saw this in real life)

Comment: @hek2mgl: Oh god.. that exists?! Yikes!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes, if I remember correctly it was a perl mysql library. It happened ~3years ago. You have been warned! ;) see you! .. (note: we detected no vulnerability, just the potential vulnerability in the perl lib)

Comment: @hek2mgl Am I handling my PDO database connection correctly? http://pastebin.com/PZA6MTdp

Comment: @methuselah Correct yes, but not most secure as you can see in the comments. If you understood 'part 1 - displaying error messages' correctly, I can continue with 'part 2 - using prepared statements', if you want. :)

Comment: btw did you found the error in your code?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit read [this](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/08/02/mysql-prepared-statements/) Maybe it's just a historical issue. But often the history 'comes back' (can I say this in english?)

Comment: @hek2mgl I copied and pasted your code and got this error: http://pastebin.com/PmyFTnQB

Comment: @methuselah My failure! When using quote() you don't have to add aditonal quotes in the query string read my update... http://pastebin.com/8E5vnT5r