# Two PDO errors when executing rowCount and second foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Been struggling at this for a couple of hours now. Can anybody point out where I'm going wrong.

The **first error** I get is:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDO::rowCount() in
pm_wall.php on line 8
Call Stack: 0.0000 643680 1. {main}()
index.php:0 0.0015 662904 2.
include('pm_wall.php')
index.php:117
```

The **second error** I get is:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in pm_wall.php on line 19

Call Stack:
    0.0000     643296   1. {main}() index.php:0
    0.0015     649864   2. include(index.php:117
```

How do I go about resolving this? Here is my code below:

```
$sql = "SELECT * from pm_msg";
$result = $pdo->query($sql);
if($pdo->rowCount() > 0 && !empty($result)) // first error occurs here
{
    foreach ($result as $row) 
    {
        $user_id = $row['user_id'];
        echo '<div id="content">
                    <div class="stbody">
                    <div class="stimg">';

        // set profile picture  

        $sql = "SELECT img FROM pm_user WHERE id=$user_id";
        $result = $pdo->query($sql);
        foreach ($result as $row) // second error occurs here
        {
            echo $row['img'];
        }

        echo '<div id="stexpandbox"><div></div>';       
        echo '</div></div></div></div>';
    }
}
else
    {
        echo 'Wanna be starting soemthing?';
    }
```

Comment: Ääämm.. did you read my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14656991/171318) from yesterday??? why don't you check the return values? crazy!!!!

Comment: @hek2mgl its my first time using PDO apologies - learning by trial and error and its proving to be rather challenging

Comment: This has nothing to do with PDO.. Its a general programming basic. !!!CHECK YOUR RETURN VALUES!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this maybe:

```
$sql = "SELECT * from pm_msg";
$result = $pdo->query($sql);
if($result->rowCount() > 0 && !empty($result)) // first error occurs here
{
    while( $row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) )
```

---

Take a little time(a day or two), and read about PDO and its usage over on [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Answer (score 3):

rowCount() has to be called on your PDO statement, not on your PDO instance !

$result->rowCount(); Reading errors might help...

Answer (score 0):

Use this option in PDO to get rows that are affected and matched:

```
PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS   => TRUE
```

If the row is not found while update for instance - it will return 0. Hope this helps.